# Combine list of dictionaries with a common key without merging values

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple list of dictionaries as follow:

```
data_aus =
[{'name': '2018,7', 'aus_ct': 13}, {'name': '2018,8', 'aus_ct': 3}, {'name': '2018,9', 'aus_ct': 3}]

data_asia = 
[{'name': '2018,7', 'asia_ct': 10}, {'name': '2018,8', 'asia_ct': 11}, {'name': '2018,9', 'asia_ct': 6}]

data_us =
[{'name': '2018,7', 'us_ct': 5}, {'name': '2018,8', 'us_ct': 8}, {'name': '2018,9', 'us_ct': 9}, {'name': '2018,10', 'us_ct': 23}]

data_uk =
[{'name': '2018,7', 'uk_ct': 15}, {'name': '2018,8', 'uk_ct': 7}, {'name': '2018,9', 'uk_ct': 13}]
```

I want to combine these lists into a single list of dictionaries based on a common key called `name`.

The result should look like:

```
data_combined = [
{'name': '2018,7', 'aus_ct': 13, 'asia_ct': 10, 'us_ct': 5, 'uk_ct':15},
{'name': '2018,8', 'aus_ct': 3, 'asia_ct': 11, 'us_ct': 8, 'uk_ct':7},
...]
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Please help.

Comment: and where's your code?

Comment: Are the variables listed under these names `data_...` or you just gave them each a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt #2.

Figured this should work:

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dicts(shared_key, *dicts):
    # Remove empty dicts (if any)
    dicts = list(filter(None, dicts))

    # Merging dicts based on shared keys
    result = defaultdict(dict)
    for dictionary in itertools.chain.from_iterable(dicts):
        result[dictionary[shared_key]].update(dictionary)

    # And converting results from {key1: dict1, key2: dict2, ...} to list of dicts [dict1, dict2, ...]
    return list(result.values())
```

And calling...

```
merge_dicts('name', data_aus, data_asia, data_us, data_uk)
```

Please let me know if there are any issues with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

1) Prepare all the data into a single list and find all the months available in your data.

```
# Put all data into a single list
all_data = [month_data for country_data in [data_aus, data_asia, data_us, data_uk] for month_data in country_data]

# Figure out the months available
months = set(map(lambda entry: entry['name'], all_data))
```

2) Merge the data by iterating month by month and joining them dictionaries.

```
data_combined = []
# Iterate month by month
for month in months:

    # Get all the data from a single month (list of dicts)
    month_data = filter(lambda entry: entry['name'] == month, all_data)

    # "Tricky part" merge the list of dictionaries
    sigle_month_data = {k: v for d in month_data for k, v in d.items()}

    # Append to the overall combined list
    data_combined.append(single_month_data)
```

3) Result

```
print(data_combined)


{'uk_ct': 15, 'asia_ct': 10, 'aus_ct': 13, 'us_ct': 5, 'name': '2018,7'}
{'uk_ct': 7, 'asia_ct': 11, 'aus_ct': 3, 'us_ct': 8, 'name': '2018,8'}
{'uk_ct': 13, 'asia_ct': 6, 'aus_ct': 3, 'us_ct': 9, 'name': '2018,9'}
{'us_ct': 23, 'name': '2018,10'}
```

Comment: Thanks but i found a simpler way.

Comment: @saran3h sure, no problem. I guess it will depend on your definition of "simpler" ;) both solutions are 7 lines of code... :D

Answer (score -1):

Attempt #1

EDIT: Fails if the order of keys differs.

Figured this solution by making a function to merge any number of dictionaries:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def merge_dicts(dicts):
    result = []
    for d in dicts:
        result = [{**u, **v} for u, v in zip_longest(result, d, fillvalue={})]

    return result
```

And just passing all the lists as input:

```
merge_dicts([data_aus, data_asia, data_us, data_uk])
```

Output is:

```
    [
      {
        "name": "2018,8",
        "aus_ct": 5,
        "asia_ct": 5,
        "us_ct": 8,
        "uk_ct": 9
      },
      {
        "name": "2018,9",
        "aus_ct": 2,
        "asia_ct": 1,
        "us_ct": 2,
        "uk_ct": 6
      },
      {
        "name": "2018,10",
        "aus_ct": 3,
        "asia_ct": 1,
        "us_ct": 3,
        "uk_ct": 11
      },
      {
        "name": "2018,11",
        "aus_ct": 9,
        "asia_ct": 1,
        "us_ct": 1,
        "uk_ct": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,6",
        "aus_ct": 7,
        "us_ct": 1,
        "uk_ct": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,8",
        "aus_ct": 7,
        "uk_ct": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,1",
        "aus_ct": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,3",
        "aus_ct": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,4",
        "aus_ct": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,5",
        "aus_ct": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,6",
        "aus_ct": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,7",
        "aus_ct": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,8",
        "aus_ct": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,9",
        "aus_ct": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "2019,10",
        "aus_ct": 1
      }
    ]
```

Thanks for the replies. Let me know if there is a better way to do so in terms of performance.

Comment: To make your output representative and meaningful - it should relate to your initial input, but it does not. For now it looks arbitrary

Comment: I don't understand what you meant but this is exactly what I wanted. If you are referring to the values not matching with the ones that I posted in the question, ofcourse they were not representative of the actual data but were used to convey the meaning.

Comment: This approach does not consider your condition "*based on a common key called `name`*" at all, and won't produce correct result in case if order of items in any dict will change, as well as with  different order of keys within a dict (entry). This is not working solution

Comment: Also, looking at your original question, you have expected result: `{'name': '2018,8', 'aus_ct': 3, 'asia_ct': 11, 'us_ct': 8, 'uk_ct':7}`, but in your answer you have `{"name": "2018,8", "aus_ct": 5, "asia_ct": 5, "us_ct": 8, "uk_ct": 9}`. Make sure you actually have the right result...

Comment: @bruno as i said above, the values are arbitrary to convey the meaning.

Comment: @saran3h, See my answer